# How to get total li tags count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get total `li tags` count which are present **`after a span tag and inside the ul tag`**.

After Getting li tags count I have to update this inside the span tag(As similar in my HTML code).

**HTML code**

```
<ul id='navigation'>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li class='IS'><span>4</span>
<!--This span value should be four as its adjucent ul contains 4 lis-->
            <ul>
                <li><span>3</span>
<!--This span value should be four as its adjucent ul contains 3 lis-->
                    <ul>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><span>5</span>
<!--This span value should be four as its adjucent ul contains 5 lis-->
                    <ul>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><span>4</span>
<!--This span value should be four as its adjucent ul contains 4 lis-->
                    <ul>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><span>4</span>
<!--This span value should be four as its adjucent ul contains 4 lis-->                    
                    <ul>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
$("#navigation ul li span+ul>li").each(function(){
cnts=$(this).length
console.log(cnts)
$("#navigation ul li span").html(cnts)
})
```

I have manually filled my required output of Li tags count inside the span tag.
My jquery doesn't provide the required result.
Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: `$("#navigation ul li span+ul>li").length;`

Comment: No need to loop the `element` to get the `length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("#navigation ul li span").text(function(){
    return $(this).next('ul').children('li').length;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='navigation'>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li class='IS'><span></span>
<!--This span value should be four as its adjucent ul contains 4 lis-->
            <ul>
                <li><span></span>
<!--This span value should be four as its adjucent ul contains 3 lis-->
                    <ul>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><span></span>
<!--This span value should be four as its adjucent ul contains 5 lis-->
                    <ul>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><span></span>
<!--This span value should be four as its adjucent ul contains 4 lis-->
                    <ul>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><span></span>
<!--This span value should be four as its adjucent ul contains 4 lis-->                    
                    <ul>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Just use `text()` method:

```
$("#navigation ul li span").text(function(){
    return $(this).next('ul').children('li').length;
});
```

Comment: Thanks you simplified my problem